# Appending contents to an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add data from my DB to an array when a user clicks a link e.g

```
echo '<a href="cart-page.php?action=add&cartid='.$row[0].'">ADD</a>'.
```

i get the id of the element and query the database to get the details of the item clicked and display it using a for loop like this(on cart-page.php):

```
$cart = $_GET['cartid'];
$cartData = array();
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product where id ='$cart'";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
          array_push($cartData, $row);
      }

     $length = count($cartData);
     for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
       echo '</tr>';
       echo ' <td class="product">'.$cartData[$i]['name'].'</td>';
      echo'<td class="quantity"><input type="text" value='.$cartData[$i]['quantity'].'   class="inputform"/></td>';

    echo '</tr>';

     }
```

My problem is array_push() isn't appending the data. Each time i navigate away from cart-page.php and click a link the previous content in cartData[] is overwritten leaving only one row in cartData[] at a time. How i can i get the data appended to cartData[] whenever i click a link like the one shown above? Thanks

Comment: you have to insert it

Comment: `cartid = "' or '1'='1'"` Boooom!

Comment: as @elcanrs wrote BOOM and your Db doesn't exists

Comment: Pardon? Are you expecting your variables to persist across different page loads?

Comment: It seems he wants it. USE `$_SESSION['cart_data']`

Comment: @elclanrs you'd have an extra closing `'` then I believe. `=]`

Comment: You need to [read up on Sessions in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) before you can solve any of your other problems.

Comment: @dhani - Read my answer, it's fairly comprehensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it need to be APpended? Why not just add it to the array and order the array at a later time?

[PHP array sorting](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $cartData[] = $row;
}
```

In addition, you should ALWAYS escape your data.

```
$cart = $_GET['cartid'];
```

The above code is vunerable to SQL injection. At the least, escape it!

```
$cart = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cartid']);
```

**EDIT**

In order to remember all previous cart additions, you will need to create a session, and add each click to it:

```
session_start();

$cartid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cartid']);

function addToCart($cartid)
{
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product where id ='{$cartid}'";

    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $_SESSION['cartItems'][] = $row;
    }
}


function getCartItems()
{
    print_r($_SESSION['cartItems']);
}
```

This will hopefully work as you expect. Sessions will retain state across browser refreshes.
To use this code, when you want to add items to the original $cartData, you need to call the function `addToCart($cartid)`. This will add the item data to the `cartItems` session array

To see whats in the cart as an array, just use `print_r($_SESSION['cartItems']);`

Comment: i already tried what you're suggesting but gave the same output that is why i thought to use array_push(). Each time this loop is executed, the contents of $cartData[] are overwritten. thats where i'm confused.

Comment: @dhani baring in mind you are only ever retrieving one record from the database, I have updated my example above, within the `while` loop, I have added a `foreach` loop. Each key in the $row array should now be added to the $cartData array with its value. If you want to give that a try?

Comment: Thanks Phil. But its the same thing. I have a page list.php with a link 'ADD'. Each time a user clicks ADD, i get the id of that element, query the DB, put the results in cartData and display them on cart-page.php. But when i go back to list.php and click another item, the items that were previously in $cartData[] are overwritten. It's kind of like a shopping cart.

Comment: Ah, so you want to retain the data across page refreshes! I understand now. You need to use sessions to do this. I have edited the code again to show how to save item data to sessions, which will do what you want :) (Hopefully!)

Comment: That works fine Phil. Thank you. The idea of using a $_SESSION variable as an array really confused me at first. Thanks for clearing it out for me.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Your issue is not that you aren't adding the item to the array, it's that you don't understand how arrays work. Arrays do not persist across pages, they are instantiated to a single runtime of a single script unless declared otherwise.

**MAJOR security flaw #1 - Sending cartid in URL:**

*Edit: I misunderstood this. Your `cartid` variable refers to a `product_id`. This is very poor variable naming, any programmer would assume this referred to an ID of a shopping cart. Whilst this security flaw is not relevant in this instance, I'm leaving it here for anyone who misunderstands your code and decides to copy it.*

Firstly, this URL is a problem:

```
echo '<a href="cart-page.php?action=add&cartid='.$row[0].'">ADD</a>'
```

This means that if I can guess another user's cart ID, I can add items to their shopping cart by visiting `cart-page.php?action=add&cartid=100` where `100` is another user's cart ID. You should process the `$cart` variable internally using a validated [session](http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_sessions_2.htm), not send them across the internet via `GET` or `POST` requests which can be user manipulated.

**MAJOR security flaw #2 - Vulnerability to SQL Injection attacks:**

The statement

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product where id ='$cart'";
```

is incredibly dangerous. Let's say I submit this in my URL (properly encoded of course):

```
cartid = 2'; DROP TABLE tbl_product; SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE cartid='
```

This will then perform the following query on your database:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_product where id ='2'; DROP TABLE tbl_product; SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE cartid='';
```

If you want to avoid this, you have a few options. The best of those options is to switch to using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), the easiest of those options is to use `mysql_real_escape_string` on everything you put into your database, like this:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product where id ='" . mysql_real_escape_string($cart) . "';";
```

**Once you've fixed the above, we can fix the rest of the code:**

First, we want to put your results into the array. As `$results` is already an associative array, you can either use it directly or store it like this:

```
$cartData = $results;
```

**Keeping products in the cart**

*Edit: I misunderstood what you were doing, you're using a variable called `$cart` to store a product ID, you need to sort out your variable names.*

In order to have an array which will persist across multiple page loads, you will need to make it a session variable, first you have to start a PHP session:

```
session_start();
```

Use a session variable like this:

```
$_SESSION['shopping_cart'] = array();
```

Then, when you 'add' a product, do this:

```
$_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$cartData['id']] = array(
    'name'=>$cartData['name'], 
    'quantity'=>1
);
```

When you change the quantity, this:

```
$_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$productId]['quantity'] = $newQuantity;
```

Now, when you display the cart, instead of displaying directly from products, insert to the array using the above first, then return the contents of `$_SESSION['shopping_cart']`.

**`foreach` was made for array transversal, use it!**

Finally, don't use an ugly `for` loop to iterate an array, just do:

```
<?php foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $product): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $product['name'] ?></td>
    <td><input type='text' value='<?php echo $product['quantity'] ?>'></input></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Hope this helps, I haven't done all the work for you, but I have given you a lot of pointers in the right direction and identified some serious issues which matter.

**Recommendations for this Project:**

A shopping site is a major undertaking, you should spend some time reading about concepts like PHP security, sessions, relational databases etc. It may seem like an unnecessary hassle, but writing clean and secure code now means that when you have to debug it and make changes, you will be able to do so much more easily.

I'd also suggest you look into some (free, open source) MVC frameworks like [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/) and [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/). These wont do all the work for you, but they will make it easier for you to keep your code well maintained and readable.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers and advice.